# Clicking on an imagebutton in ListView to navigate to an ViewPager Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview

I have an Fragment with an ListView that uses a Custom BaseAdapter. In my ListView i want to Click on an image and call a New Fragment who contains an ViewPager. Somehow i get this error message `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView` and can't figure out what the problem ist. I have tried searching but nothing explained my error message.
What am i doing wrong?

```
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addView(View) is not supported in AdapterView
        at android.widget.AdapterView.addView(AdapterView.java:452)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My onClickListener

```
                imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    MOKPagerFragment fragment2 = new MOKPagerFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.listview_fragment,fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }
            });
```

Here my Layouts

```
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

main layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    MOKPagerFragment fragment2 = new MOKPagerFragment();
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_container,fragment2);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();

                }
            });
```

Comment: Thanks! replacing R.id.listview_fragment with R.id.fragment_container was the trick. Could you maybe explain why? Im new to Android and haven't really figured out how this works.

Comment: fragment_container is the view where you can load the fragments, instead you were trying to load it in the ListView. That was the mistake. If my answer works for you? Give a up vote.